# How to get nth-child value of a td within the table using jquery based on its text

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get the number of `td:nth-child` based on the text of the cell let's say i have this table:

```
<table class="table" id="inputTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><span>mike</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td><span>eric</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td><span>jonas</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to know what is the value of `td:nth-child` when im using filter method and find the cell text which is equal to `jonas`, is it possible using jquery?

Comment: n-th means u are asking for the last child of td?

Comment: You want  index of element in tr or index of tr having that td as element.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar as td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `td` index

```
$('tr span:contains("jonas")').closest('td').index();  //output 1
```

For `tr` index

```
$('tr span:contains("jonas")').closest('tr').index();  // output 2
```

> Index start from 0 so you will need to add +1 for nth-child ..

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/a4ndk5un/)

And about *I want to know what is the value of td:nth-child* you can use something like this

```
$('tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').text()   // nth-child starts from 1 not like index from 0
```

> The above code will give you the second tr `tr:nth-child(2)` and second td
>   text on this tr `td:nth-child(2)` and if you have an input you need to
>   use `.val()` instead of `.text()`

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/a4ndk5un/2/)

Comment: Hey thank you for the the answer let me try this out i will get back to you soon =)

Comment: i apologize for the delay, this code worked perfectly thank you and also voted up for you :)

Comment: @Valkyriee Never mind .. you're welcome .. have a great day :-)